# How to get unmatched records using SQL query?

Tags: sql

Actually if i am doing INNER JOIN of two tables then i will get all matched records from the two tables.
But i want to get all the unmatched rows only.

Is there any way to do that?
Or Any JOIN available for that?

Comment: It will be helpful if you show the SQL for your matched records first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is join you can use. You need an [`OUTER JOIN`](http://infogoal.com/sql/sql-outer-join.htm), and only select rows with a `NULL` on the join condition.

Another option is to use a sub query with a [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) or [`NOT IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) as part of your main `WHERE` clause.